# why alert message not showing on ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to display a message alert on ajax by calling function getId.I am using select option list. But when I click the option list the alert message isn't getting displayed. Why is that?

This is my code :

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Dropdown ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
<label>Country</label>
<select name="country">
<div class="country" onchange="getId(this.value);">

    <option value=""> -- Select Country -- </option>

    <!-- populate value using php -->

    <?php
        $query = "SELECT * FROM country";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

        //loop

        foreach ($result as $country) {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $country["cid"]; ?>"> <?php echo $country["country"]; ?> </option>

        <?php 
            } 
        ?>

</select>
</div>
<div class="city">
<label>City</label>
<select name="city">

    <option value=""> -- Select City -- </option>

</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function getId(val){
        alert(val);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

is anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not good practice to use alert for debugging, better use console.log. The reason is that alert pauses execution, and messes up the timing

Comment: `why alert message not showing on ajax?` where is `ajax`? also `div` don't have `onchange`, it's select which have `onchange`. So shift `onchange` from `div` to `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select name="country">
<div class="country" onchange="getId(this.value);">
```

should be

```
<div class="country">
<select name="country" onchange="getId(this.value);">
```